# If statement inside ForEach causing Swift to Compile Error

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm running into a very weird error with Swift and XCode right now. I have a very basic view containing a fetcher which returns an array of strings. I won't write out that part of the code because that code is not the issue, as I've been using the fetcher for multiple builds now without issue. The probably is, I want to format the string differently depending on what its value is. Before adding this functionality in, it was building just fine with the code below;

```
ForEach(self.fetcher.fetched?.returnData ?? []) { result in
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(result.text)
    }.frame(width: metrics.size.width * 1.0)
}
```

But somehow, when I try to modify this code into what is below, it throws the ambiguous error:

```
This expression cannot be type-checked in a reasonable amount of time
```

around the entire stack which the ForEach is nested in. I have no clue why this is throwing this error, as the IF is written correctly.

```
ForEach(self.fetcher.fetched?.returnData ?? []) { result in
    if(result.text == "OtherSide") {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(result.text)
        }.frame(width: metrics.size.width * 1.0)
    } else {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Text(result.text)
        }.frame(width: metrics.size.width * 1.0)
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, kind of hard to progress because I'm stuck at this road block and can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: Generally, if the type-checker can't complete, add more types to your code, or break it down to smaller pieces.  Instead of `?? []`, you could use `?? [RESULT_TYPE]()` and you could also add types to the closure parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential solution is to put the conditional statements into a Group as in the following example:

```
struct TestView: View {

@State var array = [1,2,3,4,5]

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        ForEach(array, id: \.self) { num in
            Group {
            if num % 2 == 0 {
                Text("Even")
            } else {
                Text("Odd")
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

In this case it can be solved with not much changes as conditional branches are almost the same

```
ForEach(self.fetcher.fetched?.returnData ?? []) { result in
    VStack(alignment: result.text == "OtherSide" ? .leading : .trailing) {
       Text(result.text)
    }.frame(width: metrics.size.width * 1.0)
}
```

More common rule for such compiler error (by experience) is to decompose view builder into smaller parts, ie. function generating sub view, computable property for subview, or separating some part into completely new view struct.

Comment: I really wish I could give out multiple correct answers, because while just enclosing the entire conditional in a Group {} statement fixed my issue, your answer is probably the one that'll have much more application in other situations. I appreciate your answer a lot, I run into vague compiling issues a lot so now I have an alternative to try before resorting to making a post, thank you tons for helping out.